# Redirect user to homepage if he is not authorized to access page its not working properly

Tags: laravel

If a user creates a conference with id "2" he should be allowed to access "proj.test/conference/manage/2".

But a user that did not create the conference with id "2" should be redirected to the login page if he is not authenticated. If he is authenticated should be redirected to the homepage.

But its not working properly, if the user created the conference with id 2 he can access "proj.test/conference/manage/2" but other user that did not create this conference if accesses "proj.test/conference/manage/2" it appears an error:

```
This action is unauthorized.
```

So instead of redirecting the user to the homepage it shows this error. Do you know why is not working?

I have the store method, after storing the conference the user is redirected to the management area to manage that specific conference, for example, to manage the conference with id 2 the user is redirected to "proj.test/conference/manage/2".

Store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
         ...
    ]);
    $conference = Conference::create([
        'name' => $request->conference_name,
        ...
    ]);
}
```

Then in the AuthServiceProvider I add:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        $gate->define('access-management-area', function($user, $conference)
        {
            return $user->id == $conference->conference_creator_id;
        });
    }
```

And in the manage method I have:

```
public function manage($id){
    $conference = Conference::findOrFail($id);

    if($this->authorize('access-management-area', $conference)){
        return view('conferences.manage')->with('myconference',$conference);
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/home');

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `$this->authorize` as it does not work the same as `Gate::allows()/denies()`.

The `authorize` method will throw an `exception` if it fails, it will not return `false` for the sake of conditional comparison.

From the docs:

> If the action is not authorized, the authorize method will throw an Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException, which the default Laravel exception handler will convert to an HTTP response with a 403 status code.

So, instead, use `Gate::denies` for comparisons.

```
if(Gate::allows('access-management-area', $conference)) {
    return view('conferences.manage')->with('myconference',$conference);
} else {
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not it appears "Non-static method Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate::allows() cannot be called statically".

Comment: @JohnZ Don't use the `Contract` use the `Facade` [Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Gate.html)